# Migrating data to Google Cloud Firestore from Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I'm deciding to migrate the data of Google Cloud Datastore to Cloud Firestore. I've read all related documents & blogs, but didn't find the pricing comparison with Datastore to Firestore (though I've read all Firestore pricing & daily quota details).

I want to know the disadvantages & drawbacks of Cloud Firestore, as our data is in large-scale. I've gone through the document about choose mode (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore). Is it safe to migrate all data to Cloud Firestore in Native Mode directly or to use Firestore in Datastore mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Firestore and Datastore prices**

The price for the new Cloud Firestore DB is almost the same, except there are no `Small Operations` in the Firestore.

You can check the pricing details for the Datastore [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing). And here are the prices for the US multi-region usage as of 2019-02-01:
[image: Datastore price]

The Firestore prices details could be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing). And the prices for the US multi-region usage as of 2019-02-01 are:
[image]

Also, on March 3, 2019, Firestore prices for single region usage would be as low as 50% of multi-region prices, as stated in the [latest update](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/announcing-cloud-firestore-general-availability-and-updates) in the Google Cloud Platform blog.

**Datastore to Firestore migration**

As for the migration, it is 100% safe to migrate your Datastore app to Firestore in Datastore mode, but if you'd like to use Firestore in native mode you'd need to upgrade your application and perform manual data migration.

Just a couple of weeks ago, I have migrated one of our apps from Datastore to Firestore in Datastore mode, copying all the data with the [export and import APIs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities).